# "Practical Rails" version requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version

I am getting ready to get started in "Practical Rails: Social Networking Sites" and I was hoping that someone could clue me in on what versions of Ruby and Rails I need to get it all started.  I am currently running 1.9.2 and 3.0.9 respectively.  By skimming through the book I am going to assume that the code in there is a little outdated.  So, does anyone know what versions of Ruby and Rails would work for that book?

Thank you in advance!  (P.S. I am a beginner on this website and in programming so please be easy on me!)

P.P.S I did purchase this book from the bookstore so I would appreciate it if I didn't hear stuff like, "Get a different book."  I want to use this one.  Thank you! =)

Comment: Your purchase is a sunk cost that has no bearing on this being the correct book to use. If it really is using Rails 1 then what you actually purchased at the store is a doorstop.

Answer (score 5):

I find it hard to believe the book doesn't mention somewhere which version of Rails was used. However, since the book was published in mid 2007, it's probably using 1.2 and *maybe* has some early features of 2.0.

You're not doing yourself a favor by starting with this book. If you already had Rails experience and knew the differences between Rails 1.x, 2.x, and 3.x, then you'd probably get some value out of it. I'd recommend starting with a book that covers 3.0 at a minimum, and then revisiting this book when you've got the basics down. If people are telling you to try a different book, it's only because the changes to Rails over the last 4-5 years have been significant enough that it will be a challenge.

Comment: I just went perusing the book myself - it really, honestly, does not discuss what version of Rails it wants you to install. I couldn't believe it either.